# processing http call's response: filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Provider code:

```
import {AutoCompleteService} from 'ionic2-auto-complete';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class AutoSuggestProvider implements AutoCompleteService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public HTTP: Http) {
    console.log('Hello AutoSuggestProvider Provider');
  }
  getResults(keyword:string) {
    return this.HTTP.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/"+keyword) .map( result => { return result.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase()) ) });
  }

}
```

Problematic line:

> return this.HTTP.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/"+keyword)
>   .map( result => { return result.filter(item =>
>   item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase()) ) });

As you can see this is a problematic line it saying.

> Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Response'.

Please help me How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: try adding this 'import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

Comment: And also check if your response is empty

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

getResults(keyword:string){
return this.Http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/"+keyword).map(res=>{
  return res.json()
}).map(fil=>{
    return fil.filter(res=>{
      return res.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase())
    })
  })
```

}

In first map return as json and in second map do a filter function to filter the result based on keyword